# When will my home be furnished?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I gave my steward the gold to furnish multiple rooms in my home. It has been approximately 6 ingame days and they are still not furnished and i no longer have the option to ask my steward to do so. So, where did my money go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wild guess here, but I heard if you stay away from it for a few days, it should start to slightly furnish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It did, thanks, I went spelunking and came back, all my stuff was there